# Extract text on mouse hover in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to extract the text that appears on mouse hover on an element from the website https://idsc.cidadessustentaveis.org.br/rankings. A particular example of text of interest, is the text “Erradicacao da pobreza Pontuacao: 44,47” which appears on hovering the first bar located in the column “Desempenho por ODS”. I have tried the code below but it returns the blank text `‘’`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://idsc.cidadessustentaveis.org.br/rankings")
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
desired_elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SdgPerformanceBar__Block-sc-1yl1q71-2.fBQLcJ')))
```

I printed an attribute of the element extracted which confirmed that I have successfully gotten to the targeted element.

```
print(desired_elem.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Which returned:
`<div style="width:2.62%" class="SdgPerformanceBar__Block-sc-1yl1q71-2 fBQLcJ"></div>`

Note that by inspecting the element in Firefox I found that the element has no `innerHTML`.
I then tried to extract the text using `desired_elem.text` but I get a blank `‘’`

I also tried the code below which returned a blank as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
elem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SdgPerformanceBar__Block-sc-1yl1q71-2.fBQLcJ');
actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(elem)
actions.move_to_element(elem).perform()
```

Calling `elem.text` returned `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was close to the solution.
When hovering over those elements tooltips appearing.
These tooltips will present different texts according to element you hovered over.
Here I used your code, just added the tooltips

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
tooltip1 = "div[role='tooltip'] .MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-body1"
tooltip2 = "div[role='tooltip'] .MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-body2"

url = "https://idsc.cidadessustentaveis.org.br/rankings"

driver.get(url)

desired_elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SdgPerformanceBar__Block-sc-1yl1q71-2.fBQLcJ')))
actions.move_to_element(desired_elem).perform()
tt1_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, tooltip1))).text
tt2_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, tooltip2))).text
print(tt1_text)
print(tt2_text)
```

The output is:

```
Erradicação da pobreza
Pontuação: 44,47
```

Comment: It worked. How do you get the HTML elements for the tooltip? They don't seem to appear on browser inspection

Comment: devtools->elements. as regular